# Function Overloading in Haskell

Tags: haskell, overloading

I have a structure which represents the equation of a line in the form `m x + b` and a structure of a point

```
Line { m :: Double, b :: Double } deriving( Show, Eq )
Point { x :: Double, y :: Double } deriving( Show, Eq )
```

I want the function `perpendicular` that does the following:

```
perpendicular (Line m b) (Point x y) = 
        Line m2 b2 where
                m2 = (-1/m)
                b2 = y - m2*x
```

if given a line and a point, or a partially applied Line

```
perpendicular (Line m b) = 
        Line m2 where
                m2 = (-1/m)
```

if only given a Line.

The problem here is that I get

> Equations for `perpendicular' have different numbers of arguments

Comment: It is not possible to overload functions like that in Haskell.

Comment: Pattern matching is nice, should be extended to match the number of inputs.

Comment: You seem to want `perpendicular l x` be treated differently from `(perpendicular l) y`, but `perpendicular l x` *is exactly the same* as `(perpendicular l) x`. So you either give up partial application, or give up your style of overloading. If you want to give up partial application, then perhaps Haskell is not quite the language you should consider.

Comment: If you *really* want to do this, you can have something like `class Perpendicular where ...` and `instance Perpendicular (Line, Point) ...; instance Perpendicular Line`. If you don't like type classes (why are you using haskell in the first place?) represent the input as `Either Line (Line, Point)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case, you want the type of `perpendicular` to be `Line -> Point -> Line`, while in the second case you want it to have the type `Line -> Double -> Line`. This suggests that we can do this with a type class where we abstract over the type of the second argument:

```
class Perpendicular a where
  perpendicular :: Line -> a -> Line
```

Your first case then becomes an instance for `Point`

```
instance Perpendicular Point where
  perpendicular (Line m b) (Point x y) = Line m2 b2
    where m2 = (-1/m)
          b2 = y - m2*x
```

while the second becomes an instance for `Double`.

```
instance Perpendicular Double where
  perpendicular (Line m b) = Line m2
    where m2 = (-1/m)
```

Answer (score 12):

Haskell doesn't have function overloading in the sense you might be used to from imperative languages; I'm not even sure if type inference would still be decidable if that were allowed. The only kind of overloading you can get is with type classes, although that still doesn't allow you to define functions which take varying numbers of arguments.

Your case is a quite good example of why this can't work in haskell; If you have `perpendicular someLine` how is a haskell compiler supposed to figure out which of these functions you're talking about? Both would be valid in this situation, but the expression would have different types depending on which was picked.

Comment: Actually type classes *do* allow you to define functions which take varying number of arguments, as the `Text.Printf` module does.  It makes type inference rather brittle, though, and may be considered an ugly hack. It's certainly not appropriate for cases like this.

Comment: I don't see any real problem here. Other languages allow overloading and they handle these uncertain situations - e.g. Scala compiler, when multiple overloads can be valid, ends with an error and the user just have to make it clear which overload he wants (explicit typing, not necessarily of the method call).

Comment: @monnef Scala's type inference isn't nearly as sophisticated as Haskell's and breaks even at fairly trivial examples without explicit type annotations. It having to allow for overloading is one of the reasons for that.

Comment: @Cubic I didn't say Scala has a better type inference, just that it does support overloaded methods and has a type inference, so it is possible to support both. Even though its type inference is weaker (it's tradeoff), it still does pretty good job. In Scala (as well in Haskell) I find that I do supply quite often explicit types even when they are not necessary - it improves readability (and error messages, in a lot of cases it's even best-practice). Of course there are languages around which in my opinion fails too often in type inference, like TypeScript (still a huge improvement over JS).