# Error with a Class in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've been trying to learn classes in haskell with a little program to manipulate representation of a linear equation, but I get an error I dont understand. Can somebody tell me why this code

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

data Line = Line { m :: Double, b :: Double } deriving( Show, Eq )

class Perpendicular a where
  perpendicular :: a -> Line

instance Perpendicular (Line -> Double) where
  perpendicular (Line m b) b2 = Line m2 b2
    where m2 = (-1/m)
```

gives me this error

```
Couldn't match expected type `Line -> Double'
            with actual type `Line'
In the pattern: Line m b
In an equation for `perpendicular':
    perpendicular (Line m b) b2
      = Line m2 b2
      where
          m2 = (- 1 / m)
In the instance declaration for `Perpendicular (Line -> Double)'
```

It looks as if its ignoring b2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have written your instance as

```
instance Perpendicular (Line -> Double) where ...
```

So that means that `a ~ (Line -> Double)`.  `perpendicular` is a function with the type `a -> Line`, so for this instance it would have the concrete type `(Line -> Double) -> Line`.  That means its first argument has to be a function that takes a `Line` and returns a `Double`.  You've provided it the arguments `Line m b` and `b2`, implying that `perpendicular` should have the type `Line -> Double -> Line`, which is an entirely different type.  This is because `->` is *right associative*, meaning the following types are equivalent

```
a ->  b ->  c -> d
a ->  b -> (c -> d)
a -> (b -> (c -> d))
a -> (b ->  c -> d)
```

But these aren't

```
  a -> b  -> c  -> d   -- These are not equivalent!!
 (a -> b) -> c  -> d   -- These are not equivalent!!
((a -> b) -> c) -> d   -- These are not equivalent!!
 (a -> b  -> c) -> d   -- These are not equivalent!!
```

---

What it looks like you want is a function that takes variable arguments.  This is not the easiest thing to do in Haskell, and can lead to a lot of boilerplate and complex data structures, potentially harming efficiency while sacrificing type safety.  You could get around this somewhat by taking advantage of tuples, something like

```
instance Perpendicular (Line, Double) where
    perpendicular (Line m b, b2) = Line (-1 / m) b2

instance Perpendicular Line where
    perpendicular line = perpendicular (line, 0 :: Double)
```

Note, this still requires `FlexibleInstances`, and the type annotation on `0` is also required.  This is still making typeclasses do things they weren't meant for, but it is legal code.  You will also have to annotate a value anytime it doesn't have a declared type, e.g.

```
> perpendicular (Line 1 0, 5 :: Double)
Line {m = -1.0, b = 5.0}
> perpendicular (Line 1 0, 5)
    No instance for (Perpendicular (Line, t0))
      arising from a use of `perpendicular'
    The type variable `t0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there is a potential instance available:
      instance Perpendicular (Line, Double)
        -- Defined at <interactive>:11:10
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Perpendicular (Line, t0))
    In the expression: perpendicular (Line 1 0, 5)
    In an equation for `it': it = perpendicular (Line 1 0, 5)
```

Comment: This solution worked great! http://stackoverflow.com/a/23867455/2118130

You are right! The topic was actually variable input types.

Comment: You can remove the need for explicit type annotations in the second case by writing `instance a ~ Double => Perpendicular (Line, a) where ...`. Be careful with this, since it will create some pretty crappy error messages (try `perp (Line 1 0, ())`).